# How can I float two tables next to each other left to right?

Tags: html, css

If I had two tables?

```
<table class="one"> and... <table class="two">
```

And the CSS looks like:

```
table.one {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
table.two {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
}
```

It is not working...

Comment: and flame war in 3 ... 2 ... 1 ...

Comment: Heh, would that be because there are many ways to do it or due to my nubiness? :|

Comment: For whatever reason, people are extremely passionate about HTML tables. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Don't use position:relative, just provide width for each table in order to float properly.

```
table.one {
    float:left;
    width:45%;
}

table.two   {
    width:45%;
    float:right;
}​
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply define `float: left` to your table class it will come automatically next to each other:

```css
table {
    float:left;
    background:yellow;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Table 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blah blah</td>
        <td>blah blah</td>
        <td>blah blah</td>
    </tr>

</table>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Table 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>blah blah</td>
        <td>blah blah</td>
        <td>blah blah</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try giving them a width as well. 40% each should be a good test.

Answer (score 1):

Hey it working i give you live demo now check this

and now you can do thing two option as like this

**Option one**

```css
table.one {
  position:relative;
  float:left;
  border:solid 1px green;
}

table.two {
  position:relative;
  float:right;
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<table class="one">
  <tr>
    <td>hello demo here</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="two">
  <tr>
    <td>hello demo here 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Option two**

```html
<table class="one" align="left" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>hello demo here</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table class="two" align="right" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>hello demo here 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean it's not working?

The CSS that you have will put one table on each side of the parent element. If you're looking for them to be float directly against each other rather than on opposite sides of the parent you'll want 'float: left;' in both of them (or conversely 'float: right;' in both of them).